# Node js reverse proxy works on http but not on https

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, vite-plugin-ssr

I'm trying to deploy a vite-plugin-ssr app. I'm using CloudPanel on a digital ocean server.

I have a nodejs server that is running locally on the server and is exposed on port 3000. I am running the server with the command `npm run server` and it will fire up a server that is listening to port 3000.

Before I had my certificate installed (certbot) it was working properly. Also when I remove the certificate, it works.

After installing the certificate I get this error on my site: `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name example.nl;
  return 301 https://www.example.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name www.example.nl www1.example.nl;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:{{app_port}}/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a http/https server both on port 443&80? http = 80, https=443. Your http/80 server should just redirect to https/443. Fix that first and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name example.nl;
  return 301 https://www.example.nl$request_uri;
} // Remove this entire server config

// This one server config is enough
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name www.example.nl www1.example.nl;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent; // This will take care of the http to https permanent redirection
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:{{app_port}}/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Make sure to deploy the app properly inside `/home/<site-user>/htdocs/<domain-name>/<app-name>/dist`

Also update the directory here
[image]